# Matlab zero padding at the end of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, padding

I got in matlab an array of size A , 0 100x100 , and i want to pad it with,lets say 3 rows and 4 columns of zeros, so the next size is 103x104 . How is this possible to do in matlab?

I tried

```
         A=padarray(A,[3,4]);
```

and its not working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A=padarray(A,[2,2]);
```

This will add padding on top,bottom,left and right of matrix. The new dimension will be `104x104`. Padding can be done symmetrically only. In `[2,2]`,

> First `2` represents 2 rows in top and 2 rows in bottom of matrix (row size 2+100+2)
>
> Second `2` represents 2 columns in left and 2 columns in right of matrix (column size 2+100+2)

If you want to do padding only in right and bottom. Then use the below code.

```
rowPad=3;
colPad=4;
A=padarray(A,[rowPad,colPad]);
A(1:rowPad,:)=[];
A(:,1:colPad)=[];
```

The new dimension will be `103x104`.

Comment: Can you answer to me , if i want to align the two matrices (that represent two images) what should i do?

Comment: @alphonse Please ask this as a new question and also include in it what you meant by the word align? Are you talking about aligning two similar images or just making their dimensions same. Also what processing will be later done on thoses images.

Comment: A is original image,and B is the blurred image. I want to align them so that i can find parameters of the filter (found by fspecial(param1,param2,' ... ')) . So in order to specify the images A and B should be aligned. Images A and B are given to me and have different but close enough dimensions

Comment: @alphonse Please ask this as a new question. Since this is an already answered post other community members wont notice it. You wont know from whom you will get the best answer. Also it will be helpful for others who may face the same need as yours in the future.

Comment: @alphonse Please don't update the question like that. Please change it back and ask this as a new question using [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @alphonse If you want put the new questions link here and I will be glad to help you.